# $h$ such that $f(a)+ha=f(b)+fb$ exists, for a function $f:[a\,..b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$; proof of the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:[a\,..b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function continuous on $[a\,..b]$ and differentiable on $(a\,..b)$. Let $F:[a\,..b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined as $F(x)=f(x)+hx$, where $h \in \mathbb R$.

I'm reading the [Proofwiki proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mean_Value_Theorem) of the mean value theorem and there is a part I struggle to understand:

> Let us choose the constant $h$ such that $F(a)=F(b)$

How do we know that such a constant even exists?

Comment: Just solve $f(a)+ha=f(b)+hb$.

Answer (score 0):

We want $$F(a)=f(a)+ha=f(b)+hb=F(b)$$  so take $$h=\frac {f(b)-f(a)}{a-b}$$  Of course this expression assumes that $a\neq b$ but if $a=b$ just take $h=0$.

Answer (score 0):

We want :

$$F(a)=F(b) \implies f(a)+ha=f(b)+hb$$

$$ f(a)-f(b)=h(b-a) \implies h= \frac{f(a)-f(b)}{b-a}$$

Obviously, $a \neq b$ , because then it will have only one value in it's domain I.e. it will be point function, where it makes no sense to talk continuity and differentiability.